# How practical is it to have some JS libraries to be an asset in a dart program?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Hello Dart Community,
    I am curious to know the practicality of using a javascript library (say a visualizing js like D3.js, etc) within your dart app?

I currently am building an app that tries to take data and do some analytics. To do this, I would like to visualize the data clearly.

I know there is js dart interop. https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/

Does this have a good enough functionality to be used in communicating with a robust JS library? What is the catch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is used a lot. Just take a look on the questions  here on SO [dart-js-interop](/questions/tagged/dart-js-interop). It's not too comfortable currently but thre is work going on to make a better developer experience.
There are Dart packages that provide wrappers for d3.js. I have no idea how well they work though:

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/charted
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/d3d
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/d3

At least the code can give you and idea how to use d3 from Dart.

Comment: Charted looks promising. 
Do you have any idea if I want to participate in growing the pub packages like https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/charted.
Is it the usual process through git (forking a repo) or should I communicate with them through their contact info?
Thanks!

Comment: Sure, fork, clone, commit, create pull request. Usually highly appreciated. It might be a good idea to create an issue first about what you want to add/change and then see what response you get from the maintainer. For simple things just creating a pull request might be easier.

Comment: I'm using charted on production. It's ok library. Not exited but enough.

Answer (score 3):

I'm prefer using wrappers to use js libs to avoid use dart interop in all places in project.

The worse functionality using JS libs is when lib is a JS polymer component. You may be would to generate wrapper with [custom_element_apigen](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/custom_element_apigen).

For other js libraries you can write wrapper with your forces. You can use some wrapper generator too but I never have this experience.